# how to add eventlistener on button click if it already have function to button onclick

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="add-gift-message">
  <input type="checkbox" id="allow_gift_options" value="1">
  <label>Add Gift Message</label>
</div>
<div class="buttons-set form-buttons btn-only" id="billing-buttons-container">
  <input type="button" class="button" onclick="AddEventHandler();"><span>Continue</span>
</div>
```

can any one tell me how to add listener on onclick of button but already its having function on buttons onclick and how to check the checkbox on button onclick function here i am providing jsfiddel for that please help me in advance thanks for reply
http://jsfiddle.net/jWUB4/15/

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try:

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

button.onclick = function(e) {
    fireFirst(e);
    fireSecond(e);
    etc....
}

// first function to fire when button is clicked...
function fireFirst(e)
{
    // code goes here
}

// second function to fire when button is clicked...
function fireSecond(e)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Basically, you have a wrapper function that contains all the other functions you want to fire when the button is clicked.